# can't combine Two shuffle values

Tags: flutter, dart

i have two lists and i'm making shuffle to get a random element but when i combine the tow shuffle values i get this error :

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
> (Documentation)  Try checking to see if you're using the correct API;
> there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect.
> Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.

code:

```
final randomEmoji = emojis.shuffle();
final randomlLast = last.shuffle();

final finalText = randomlLast + randomEmoji;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed just call last.shuffle(); , don't assign it to a new variable

Answer (score 1):

The shuffle method does not return a new list. It shuffles the original list in place and returns void hence the error you are getting.

If you want to get a random element from each list, you can do something like this:

```
import 'dart:math';

final random = Random();

final randomFromEmoji = emojis[random.nextInt(emojis.length)];
final randomFromLast = last[random.nextInt(last.length)];

final finalText = '$randomFromLast$randomFromEmoji';
```

If you just want to concantenate shuffled version of both list, do the below:

```
final random = Random();
emojis.shuffle(random);
last.shuffle(random);

final finalList = last + emojis;
```

Where `finalList` is the combined shuffle list.